Problem with automatic row switching of datagridview
I have a problem with my datagrid when I do automatic row switching. In an invisible column, it shows me an exception: the active cell cannot be set as an invisible cell.
Public Class Form1
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim modeEdition As Boolean
    Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            row = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            column = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            column += 1
            If column = DataGridView1.ColumnCount Then
                row += 1
                If row = DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
                    If row = DataGridView1.RowCount Then
                        If DataGridView1.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
                            'bindingSource1.AddNew()
                        Else
                            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                column = 0
            End If
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(column)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Columns(2).Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class


